# SQL Percentage Queries

Tags: sql, percentage

I'm a beginner in SQL and my question is about calculating a percentage of the overall disclosed total from a table called merged. I want to calculate the number of 'SUPPORT' from committee_position (a column in the table merged)

How to calculate the percentage in that case. 
I start with:

```
SELECT Sum (amount) *100
from merged
where merged.committee_position == 'SUPPORT';
```

Help me continue it, Thank you

Comment: SQL has `=`, not `==` for equals.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, no images.)

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  I don't see what `amount` has to do with the question.

Answer (score 1):

*If* I followed you correctly, you can do conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    100.0 * sum(case when committee_position = 'SUPPORT' then amount else 0 end) / sum(amount)
from merged
```

This gives you the percentage of amount that have `committee_position = 'SUPPORT'` over the total amount in the table.

Comment: Thank you! this worked, I appreciate your prompt response.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```
SELECT a.Support_Amount/b.Total_Amount*100
FROM (SELECT Sum (amount) as Support_Amount
from merged
where merged.committee_position = 'SUPPORT') as a
CROSS JOIN 
(SELECT Sum (amount) as Total_Amount
from merged) as b
```